# How can I read lines from file and wait for new lines to be added like tail -f does

Tags: rust

I'm reading lines from a file like this:

```
let file = File::open("/tmp/log.txt").unwrap();
let reader = BufReader::new(&file);

for line in reader.lines() {
 // process lines
}
```

from another process I am appending to the file

```
echo "hello" >> /tmp/log.txt
echo "world" >> /tmp/log.txt
...
```

after some time more messages can be appended to the log.

Currently I am having an issue where the loop exits as soon as all the current lines have been read. What I would like is for it to wait (block) until more lines are pushed to the log.

I've noticed that if I open `stdin()` , the `for` loop will block and wait on stdin for more lines to come in.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior?

Comment: `>` does not append to a file.

Comment: See [the rust coreutils](https://github.com/uutils/coreutils/tree/master/src/uu/tail) for more information. tl; dr: it works by periodically sleeping, then polling the file again to see if the file changed size.

Comment: fixed the typo i had

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`notify` crate](https://crates.io/crates/notify) to watch for file changes. Then if you track the size of the file, then you can use the [`Seek` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html) to [`seek(SeekFrom::Start(last_file_end))`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) after every change, and only read the new contents.

To recreate `tail -f /tmp/log.txt`, you can do something like this:

```rust
use notify::{watcher, DebouncedEvent, RecursiveMode, Watcher};
use std::fs::{self, File};
use std::io::{Read, Seek, SeekFrom};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let path = std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap();

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let mut watcher = watcher(tx, Duration::from_millis(100)).unwrap();
    watcher.watch(&path, RecursiveMode::NonRecursive).unwrap();

    let mut contents = fs::read_to_string(&path).unwrap();
    let mut pos = contents.len() as u64;

    print!("{}", contents);

    loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(DebouncedEvent::Write(_)) => {
                let mut f = File::open(&path).unwrap();
                f.seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos)).unwrap();

                pos = f.metadata().unwrap().len();

                contents.clear();
                f.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();

                print!("{}", contents);
            }
            Ok(_) => {}
            Err(err) => {
                eprintln!("Error: {:?}", err);
                std::process::exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thus running it by doing `cargo run -- /tmp/log.txt` replicates the behavior of `tail -f /tmp/log.txt`, in which it prints the contents of the file, and subsequently outputs additional contents as it is appended.

Note that it does not handle truncation nor deletion. In that case check the [`DebouncedEvent`](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.15/notify/enum.DebouncedEvent.html) enum variants, and modify as needed. Additionally, the `unwrap`s should probably be handled a bit better.

---

You can of course still use [`lines()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.lines) if you want to:

```rust
let mut f = File::open(&path).unwrap();
f.seek(SeekFrom::Start(pos)).unwrap();

pos = f.metadata().unwrap().len();

let reader = BufReader::new(f);
for line in reader.lines() {
    println!("> {:?}", line);
}
```

Comment: `std::fs::metadata(&path)?.len()` is prolly cheaper

Comment: @David天宇Wong I disagree, `f` is already a file descriptor, so it would use `fstat`, whereas `path` is not, so it uses `stat` and has to resolve that first

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a more up to date answer:

```rust
use std::io::{Seek, BufReader, BufRead};
use notify::{Watcher, RecursiveMode, Result, RecommendedWatcher, Config};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // get file
    let path = std::env::args().nth(1).unwrap();

    // get pos to end of file
    let mut f = std::fs::File::open(&path)?;
    let mut pos = std::fs::metadata(&path)?.len();

    // set up watcher
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    let mut watcher = RecommendedWatcher::new(tx, Config::default())?;
    watcher.watch(path.as_ref(), RecursiveMode::NonRecursive)?;

    // watch
    for res in rx {
        match res {
            Ok(_event) => {
                // ignore any event that didn't change the pos
                if f.metadata()?.len() == pos {
                    continue;
                }

                // read from pos to end of file
                f.seek(std::io::SeekFrom::Start(pos + 1))?;

                // update post to end of file
                pos = f.metadata()?.len();

                let reader = BufReader::new(&f);
                for line in reader.lines() {
                    println!("> {:?}", line.unwrap());
                }
            }
            Err(error) => println!("{error:?}"),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: OB1: `pos + 1` should be just `pos`.